# Choosing reference point in General plane motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames

Hello i am now studying general plane motion from Hibbler dynamics , now for choosing reference point to calculate the moment about , does this point need to be in the body frame? , means to move with it , or can it be outside of the body fixed frame ? and if yes how calculations would be ? Because he said in rotation about fixed axis it won’t matter but he didn’t talk about it in general plane motion